# ROS Answers SE migration: rviz in Qt

Tags: rviz, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I spent about an hour to find a similar question (and an answer), but could not succeed.

I have a Qt-based GUI application to send messages to my robot from a remote cockpit PC. To see the effect of these messages, I am running rviz as a separate application on the cockpit PC. Now I wish to embed rviz into my GUI, so that I have a single application that does both.

Is it possible to embed rviz into Qt without rewriting a major part of rviz? If yes, then where is this explained? Is there an example/tutorial?

I'm using qt 4.7.0 32-bit and ROS DiamondBack, on Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10105/rviz-in-qt/) by [mittik](https://answers.ros.org/users/619/mittik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2011-05-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that it is not easily possible. As far as I know it is based on wxWidgets and OGRE.

Maybe the other way around is easier for you: Embedding your application into rviz.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mittik](https://answers.ros.org/users/619/mittik/) on 2011-05-30**:
Thanks for the clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yep, someone has made it work with the new Qt version: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.science.robotics.ros.user/15376

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

that's probably the tutorial you are looking for: http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Librviz%3A%20Incorporating%20RViz%20into%20a%20Custom%20GUI

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2014-08-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2